# Spy on a tikz plot generated by tikzDevice

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

I'd like to magnify a certain part of the plot (marked in the picture) using the tikz spy package. The code was generated by tikzDevice package for R. Every time I try to insert `\spy`, I get `undefined control sequence` error. I'd appreciate any help.

And that's the part I'd like to magnify (no need for precise coordinates - I can figure it out myself; I just need help getting any magnification to work): [image: part of the plot]

Thanks.

Solved. Updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Created by tikzDevice version 0.10.1 on 2017-04-17 01:16:10
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt, spy using outlines=    {circle,red,magnification=3,size=4cm, connect spies}]
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0)     rectangle (433.62,271.01);
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (433.62,271.01);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.6pt,line join=round,line     cap=round,fill=fillColor] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (433.62,271.01);
\spy [blue] on (119,40) in node [right] at (255,145);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you `spy this scope`/`spy using outlines`/`spy using overlays`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the problem. I realised I've mistakenly put `spy using outlines` in the wrong place in my previous attempts and then got rid of it altogether.

Comment: Please insert your code in the question, not linking to a remote source. If the website changes something or is down, your question becomes useless for others who are interested in the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I pasted the relevant part.